# React interval using old state inside of useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-functional-component

I ran into a situation where I set an interval timer from inside useEffect.  I can access component variables and state inside the useEffect, and the interval timer runs as expected.  However, the timer callback doesn't have access to the component variables / state.  Normally, I would expect this to be an issue with "this".  However, I do not believe "this" is the the case here.  No puns were intended.  I have included a simple example below:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [intervalSet, setIntervalSet] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!intervalSet) {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(`count=${count}`);
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 1000);
      setIntervalSet(true);
    }
  }, [count, intervalSet]);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default App;
```

The console outputs only count=0 each second.  I know that there's a way to pass a function to the setCount which updates current state and that works in this trivial example.  However, that was not the point I was trying to make.  The real code is much more complex than what I showed here.  My real code looks at current state objects that are being managed by async thunk actions.  Also, I am aware that I didn't include the cleanup function for when the component dismounts.  I didn't need that for this simple example.

Comment: The first time you run the `useEffect` the `intervalSet` variable is set to true and your interval function is created using the current value (0). on subsequent runs of the `useEffect` you do not recreate the interval causing the issue. To fix this issue remove `count` from the `useEffect` dependency array and change `setCount(count + 1)` to `setCount(currentCount => currentCount + 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run the `useEffect` the `intervalSet` variable is set to `true` and your interval function is created using the current value (0).

On subsequent runs of the `useEffect` it does not recreate the interval due to the `intervalSet` check and continues to run the existing interval where count is the original value (0).

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

The `useState` set function can take a function which is passed the current value of the state and returns the new value, i.e. `setCount(currentValue => newValue);`

An interval should always be cleared when the component is unmounted otherwise you will get issues when it attempts to set the state and the state no longer exists.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    // State to hold count.
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    // Use effect to create and clean up the interval 
    // (should only run once with current dependencies)
    useEffect(() => {
        // Create interval get the interval ID so it can be cleared later.
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            // use the function based set state to avoid needing count as a dependency in the useEffect.
            // this stops the need to code logic around stoping and recreating the interval.
            setCount(currentCount => {
                console.log(`count=${currentCount}`);
                return currentCount + 1;
            });
        }, 1000);

        // Create function to clean up the interval when the component unmounts.
        return () => {
            if (intervalId) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }
    }, [setCount]);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default App;
```

You can run the code and see this working below.

```js
const App = () => {
    // State to hold count.
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

    // Use effect to create and clean up the interval 
    // (should only run once with current dependencies)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Create interval get the interval ID so it can be cleared later.
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            // use the function based set state to avoid needing count as a dependency in the useEffect.
            // this stops the need to code logic around stoping and recreating the interval.
            setCount(currentCount => {
                console.log(`count=${currentCount}`);
                return currentCount + 1;
            });
        }, 1000);

        // Create function to clean up the interval when the component unmounts.
        return () => {
            if (intervalId) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }
    }, [setCount]);

  return <div></div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This solution does not work, it creates multiple intervals. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8bywd/

Comment: @Nitsew This was not creating extra intervals, it had an extra console.log inside the interval which is now removed.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I agree that this answer does work as a counter.  There are actually simpler examples of a useEffect second counter on the internet.  I have edited my original question to try to make my question more clear. I'm trying to access current state objects once a second from within a calback function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the interval is created only once and keeps pointing to the same state value. What I would suggest - move firing the interval to separate `useEffect`, so it starts when the component mounts. Store interval in a variable so you are able to restart it or clear. Lastly - clear it with every unmount.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [intervalSet, setIntervalSet] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIntervalSet(true);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = intervalSet ? setInterval(() => {
      setCount((c) => {
         console.log(c);
         return c + 1;
      });
    }, 1000) : null;

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [intervalSet]);

  return null;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more complex implementation as mention [in your comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492654/react-interval-using-old-state-inside-of-useeffect#comment114038719_64492802), you should try using a ref perhaps. For example, this is a custom interval hook I use in my projects. You can see there is an effect that updates callback if it changes.

This ensures you always have the most recent state values and you don't need to use the custom updater function syntax like `setCount(count => count + 1)`.

```js
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(() => savedCallback.current(), delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [delay])
}

// Usage

const App = () => {
  useInterval(() => {
    // do something every second
  }, 1000)

  return (...)
}
```

This is a very flexible option you could use. However, this hook *assumes* you want to start your interval when the component mounts. Your code example leads me to believe you want this to start based on the state change of the `intervalSet` boolean. You could update the custom interval hook, or implement this in your component.

It would look like this in your example:

```js
const useInterval = (callback, delay, initialStart = true) => {
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(initialStart)
  const savedCallback = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (start && delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(() => savedCallback.current(), delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [delay, start])
  
  // this function ensures our state is read-only
  const startInterval = () => {
    setStart(true)
  }
  
  return [start, startInterval]
}

const App = () => {
  const [countOne, setCountOne] = React.useState(0);
  const [countTwo, setCountTwo] = React.useState(0);
  
  const incrementCountOne = () => {
    setCountOne(countOne + 1)
  }
  
  const incrementCountTwo = () => {
    setCountTwo(countTwo + 1)
  }
  
  // Starts on component mount by default
  useInterval(incrementCountOne, 1000)

  // Starts when you call `startIntervalTwo(true)`
  const [intervalTwoStarted, startIntervalTwo] = useInterval(incrementCountTwo, 1000, false)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>started: {countOne}</p>
      <p>{intervalTwoStarted ? 'started' : <button onClick={startIntervalTwo}>start</button>}: {countTwo}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @kinduser your logic flow is "if `count` or `intervalSet` changes, create an interval" so every time the count changes, you are overwriting and creating a new interval. In your case, you are creating a new interval every second.

Comment: @kinduser I removed my downvote on your question, you are right.